# Excel and VBscript giving me Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am writing a VBScript to create a calendar and at this line, I am getting an error that says

```
With objExcel.Range("A1:U28")
    '.FormatConditions.Add xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=TODAY()" --- CRASH
    objExcel.Range("A1:U28").FormatConditions.Add xlCellValue,xlEqual,"=Today()" // CRASH
    .FormatConditions(1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
End With
```

Error: Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Anyone know why this isn't working or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

In VBScript, you have to explicitly define constants like `xlCellValue` (and you can't use named parameters via `:=`). cf [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info)

Comment: I am still stuck in my VBA world apparently